# cat files with filenames in .tsv

Tags: bash, text-files, filenames, cat

I have file names provided in a tab separated file.

Ex:

```
file1 file2 file3
file4 file5
file6 file7 file8 file9 file10
file11 file12
```

......and so on.

I need to be able to do:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > newfile1
cat file4 file5 > newfile2
cat file5 file7 file8 file9 file10 > newfile3
```

.....

There are a total of 140 lines to this file, and multiple file names per row. Within each row I need to concatenate the files. Each file name has a uniq name, so I need to name the new file something different.

There are leading characters in each file prefix that I would like to use to rename. For example, (file1) A1-2_B1.txt and (file2) A1-4_B1.txt would be concatenated to file A1_B1.txt

Any suggestion? All help is appreciated.

I know I can use

```
 (cat inputs.txt | -n 140 cat) >> newfile.txt
```

to use a file with filenames per individual line to make a single new file. However, I am having trouble with the multiple files per line, to make multiple new files.

I'm wondering if I put all output filenames into a text file, such as:

```
A1_B2.txt
A2_B3.txt
..etc...
```

and using something like:

```
 (cat inputs.txt | cat) >> (cat outputs.txt)
```

if it will work.

Comment: Letting us know what all you have tried so far will be appreciated too.

Comment: @Technext. See edits.

Comment: @jm666. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using the answers from chepner and glenn jackman, I was able to make a script to get exactly what I needed. Using glenn jackman's version of chepners I was able to rename the files given an outputs.txt, and then I easily modified chepners's original to remove the ones from the input file that are not longer needed since the new files were made.

Here 's the combination of both:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "Getting inputs and output file names:"

paste $1 $2 | while IFS=$'\t' read -a line; do
        cat "${line[@]:1}" > "${line[0]}"
done

wait

echo "Removing old files"

while IFS=$'\t' read -a names; do
        rm "${names[@]}"
done < $2
```

~

Comment: To remove the old files, just add `rm "${line[@]:1}"` into the first loop.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks. can you comment and edit your answer? and I'll remove mine..

Comment: No, leave this one: removing the files was not a requirement in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` to transform the file into a script, then pipe into a shell to execute:

```
awk '{print "cat", $0, ">", "newfile" ++c}' inputs.txt | sh
```

If you have an "output names" file that corresponds line-for-line with 
the input file, then

```
awk '{getline out < "outputs.txt"; print "cat", $0, ">", out}' inputs.txt | sh
```

---

another approach to chepner's bash solution:

```
paste outputs.txt inputs.txt | while IFS=$'\t' read -a line; do
    cat "${line[@]:1}" > "${line[0]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i=0
while IFS=$'\t' read -a names; do
    cat "${names[@]}" > "newfile$((++i))"
done < inputs.txt
```

should do the trick. Each line is read into an array, and the contents of that array is used as the argument list to `cat`.

If you have a separate file that contains the output names:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -a names;
      read output <&3; do
    cat "${names[@]}" > "$output"
done < inputs.txt 3< outputs.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to give an additional file with names for the newfiles with your script?

Comment: I also only get one output file. THe one from the last row listed in the inputs.

Comment: Strange; what is the name of the single output file?

Comment: newfile1 is all. for last line in inputs.

Comment: Are you sure you have `i=0` *before* the loop, not inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

After many different solutions, another `perl` based:

```
perl -nle 'system qq{cat $_ > out$.}' < input.txt
```

(works, if the filenames doesn't contains spaces)